# Como posso criar eventos de uma maneira mais segura?

Tags: c#, eventos

Estou criando eventos de acordo com o código abaixo, no entanto parece ser uma maneira um pouco perigosa, visto que se não houver um cancelamento do evento ele irá acumular a cada "disparo" do evento, ou seja, se ele ocorrer três vezes na quarta vez ele irá ser executado quatro vezes e não somente uma. Como posso reescrever o código para que ele o cancelamento do evento não dependa de um "=-" ?

```
 private static MainWindow _mainWindow;
    public static void Start(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    public static void AtivaProgressBar()
    {
        _mainWindow.ProgressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;

        Suporte.Processo();

        Suporte.OnProcessoLongo += Suporte_OnProcessoLongo;
    }

    static void Suporte_OnProcessoLongo()
    {

        _mainWindow.StackPanel.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            _mainWindow.ProgressBar2.IsIndeterminate = true;

            MessageBox.Show("Call me");

            Suporte.OnProcessoLongo =- Suporte_OnProcessoLongo;

        }));
    }

public class Suporte
{
    public delegate void ProcessoLongo();

    public static event ProcessoLongo OnProcessoLongo;

    public static void Processo()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew((() => {

            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            RaiseProcessoLongo();
        }));
    }

    static void RaiseProcessoLongo()
    {
        if (OnProcessoLongo != null)
            OnProcessoLongo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ou seja, quer remover todas as subscrições do evento de uma só vez?

Comment: @Omni não necessariamente, o que pretendo é fazer com que uma vez o evento for assinado não precisar o desenvolvedor remover a subscrição. Suponha um Framework que contenha uma classe que possui eventos, da maneira como está sempre que o desenvolvedor assina um evento ele precisa remover a subscrição, eu queria que essa remoção fosse feita pela própria Framework e não pelo developer.

Comment: Eu ia tentar ajudar mas este código parece ter problemas de concepção. Ou seja, na forma atual ou é muito amplo ou não está claro.

Comment: O correto é voce colocar a atribuição do evento += em um lugar que só será chamado uma vez (PAGE_LOAD?)

Comment: @PauloHDSousa mas como se trata de um evento, ele pode ser acionado mais de uma vez. A ideia é fazer algo semelhante aos eventos de UIElemtent que os eventos (GotFocus, LostFocus, etc) são "chamados" e não necessitam da remoção da subscrição.

Comment: @julius_cesars o EVENTO pode ser acionado mais de uma vez, a inscrição dele não deveria.

Comment: @julius_cesars Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 3):

A maneira mais fácil é remover um notificador de evento de um evento e depois adicionar ele novamente, assim ele não ficará duplicado.
Não tem problema em remover a notificação sem ter adicionado antes.

```
    public static void AtivaProgressBar()
    {
        _mainWindow.ProgressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;

        Suporte.Processo();

        Suporte.OnProcessoLongo -= Suporte_OnProcessoLongo;
        Suporte.OnProcessoLongo += Suporte_OnProcessoLongo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**DDD – Domain Events**

Existe um padrão de projeto especifico para essa questão, chama-se DDD – Domain Events.

Esse padrão tem como escopo que as camadas se comuniquem por eventos.

**O que é ?**

"Domain Events, são eventos que fazem sentido para o domínio, ou seja, coisas que precisam acontecer quando determinada ação ocorre, por exemplo, um sistema de transportes, poderíamos ter eventos como: “carga entregue”, “carga em transporte” ou “carga em separação”.

E explicando um pouco a introdução, dizemos que Domain Events são um tipo de mensagem que descreve algo que aconteceu no passado que é de interesse do negócio, usamos isso para separar todas as preocupações técnicas do domínio, com isso, suas operações de escrita ficam todas encapsuladas em comandos na forma de enventos."

**Como implementar ?**

Segue tutorial

http://viniciusmussak.net/2015/08/30/domain-events/